# Read all the array values in file appsetting.json on the screen and read book information with id = 555

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "book": [
    {
      "id": "555",
      "language": "C",
      "edition": "First",
      "author": "Dennis Ritchie "
    },
    {
      "id": "666",
      "language": "C#",
      "edition": "Second",
      "author": "Anders Hejlsberg"
    }
  ]
}
```

In Startup.cs, I just get one value by index, below I get by id

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(Configuration.GetSection("book:0:id").Value);
        });
    }
```

There are my codes above, I only get one value, How to get all the array?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var list = new List<MyBookClass>();
Configuration.GetSection("book").Bind(list);
foreach(var book in list)
{ 
   //do what ever you want with your list of books
}
```

You will need to add a reference to nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder

Also you will need to create the MyBookClass like this:

```
public class MyBookClass
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string language { get; set; }
   public string edition { get; set; }
   public string author { get; set; }
}
```

This is the common pattern for reading settings in asp.net core

Then you can do whatever you want with the list.